# AWS Docker Golang. 'eb deploy' error

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy golang docker to AWS.

1. I use predefined  FROM golang:1.4.2-onbuild
2. eb local run - works beautifully, no problem.
3. If I zip and upload the zip file, it works on AWS no problem.
4. ...but when I try 'eb deploy' I keep getting this error.

Any suggestion, please.

Thank you.

```
bash-3.2$ eb deploy
WARNING: Deploying a previously deployed commit.
INFO: Environment update is starting.                               
INFO: Deploying new version to instance(s).                         
WARN: Failed to build Docker image aws_beanstalk/staging-app, retrying...
ERROR: Failed to build Docker image aws_beanstalk/staging-app: urce files in /go/src/app
[0mtime="2015-08-28T03:48:44Z" level="info" msg="The command [/bin/sh -c go-wrapper install] returned a non-zero code: 1" . Check snapshot logs for details.
ERROR: [Instance: i-bf189879] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...n-zero code: 1" 
Failed to build Docker image aws_beanstalk/staging-app: urce files in /go/src/app
[0mtime="2015-08-28T03:48:44Z" level="info" msg="**The command [/bin/sh -c go-wrapper install] returned a non-zero code: 1**" . Check snapshot logs for details. 
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03build.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
ERROR: Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-bf189879'. Aborting the operation.
ERROR: Failed to deploy application.
```

Comment: Can you get the snapshot logs from the web interface? It can give you more information. I don't know if it's also accessible with the `eb` command, but it should be.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Here is the detailed debug log. Hopefully you can see something here. [log file](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1pR_10oNtDqCvg0df4Jhh9G18LsydbRNmt9H00X_gROM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I don't see what the error was in that log. The log I had in mind has a different format from what I can remember. It would show logs from docker as well. You can get it if you go to your environment, click on Logs on the menu to the left then "Last 100 Lines" in the "Request Logs" dropdown. You could ask for "Full Logs" too,  but last 100 is usually enough.

Comment: Here are the last 100 lines of log: [Last 100 lines](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xqxYvDCXNdanGh5eVgFG8ofdIg6L9g3Vib9cZzbpZkI/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you, the only thing that seems relevant is `no buildable Go source files in /go/src/app`. It looks like it can't find your go source files but I have no idea why. :(

Answer (score 0):

Move your project folder into

```
/go/src/{your_project}
```

The problem was that my project folder was outside $GOPATH folder. Once I fixed that, 'eb deploy' starts to work.

Comment: Instead of a second answer I suggest you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32290477/edit) the first to contain this information (and then delete this answer). In general if more answers get added there is no guarantee on the order in which someone will see/read the answers (default sort is by votes) so your correction/reference to your first answer doesn't work well.